# Python: How to efficiently reformat numeric strings?

Tags: python, string, numbers

*UPDATE*: This question has been revised for clarity.  The accepted answer addressed the original question, which included a precision requirement. This requirement has since been removed.

**REVISED**: I have a regex function that pulls numbers from any string creating a "numeric string".  For each numeric string, I want a separate function that reformats them to appear float-like.  Example:

```
format_str("23.05")
"23.05"

format_str("23")
"23.0"
```

The latter example illustrates the must significant conversion, from int-like to float-like, which effectively appends `".0"` to an int-like string.  Float-like strings may remain unchanged.

Here is a sample of numeric strings, comprising integer and float-like values:

```
import numpy as np

# Build a random sampling of integers and floats
size = 100000
float_arr = np.random.uniform(1, 5000, size=size/2.)
integer_arr = np.random.randint(1, 5000, size=(size/2.))
mixed_set = set(float_arr) | set(integer_arr)
numeric_strs = list(str(num) for num in mixed_set)
```

Here is a test:

```
def test_equiv_strs(func, numeric_strs):
    """Verify the function has the same result as type-conversion operation."""
    for num_str in numeric_strs:
        actual = func(num_str)
        expected = str(float(num_str))                     # double type converstion
        nt.assert_equal(actual, expected)
        nt.assert_is_instance(actual, str)
        #print("Orig. {}, Non-convert {}, Conversions {}".format(num_str, actual, expected))

test_equiv_strs(format_str, numeric_strs)
```

In Python, how do I most efficiently format numeric strings to float-like strings?

---

**ORIGINAL**: I want a function that formats numeric strings with a precision of one decimal.  The function should return a string.

```
format_str("23")
"23.0"

format_str("23.0")
"23.0"
```

Note: I know the following works, but **I prefer to avoid type conversions**, i.e.   `str` to `float` to `str`.

```
def format_str(number):
    return "{:.1f}".format(float(number))
```

How do I accomplish this in Python without converting the string type?

Comment: Why don't you want to convert to float?  (One might even ask why these numbers are stored as strings in the first place.)

Comment: If the input is `'23.66'`, do you want an output of `'23.6'` or `'23.7'`? Also, if you think the string-to-float conversion would be a major performance hit, you might have an unrealistic view of what's eating your runtime.

Comment: @pylang: If you're asking for another way to do it, you don't know whether it's necessary or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) with `'.'` as separator:

```
def format_str(number):
    r, _, l = number.partition('.')
    return r + '.' + (l[0] if l else '0')
```

**Trial**:

```
>>> format_str('23')
'23.0'
>>> format_str('23.0')
'23.0'
>>> format_str('23.')
'23.0'
>>> format_str('23.123')
'23.1'
```

Comment: Elegant.  Although, I will use `"".join([r, ".", ...])` instead of concatenation.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
def format_str(s):
    working = s + ('.0' if s[-1]!='.' else '0')    # 1
    return working[:working.index('.')+2]          # 2
```

1. Put an extra `.0` on the end for consistency.  If there's already a decimal point in the string, the `.0` will be ignored.  Thanks to @user2357112 for the `1.` testcase, which the `if`/`else` handles.
2. Extract everything up through the `.` and the character following it.

This function doesn't modify any characters in the string, so if you pass it `abc` you'll get `abc.0`.  Also, per your question, this is *formatting*, not *rounding*.  If you want rounding you need something more complicated, probably BCD or rational math if you want to avoid 0.999999... situations.

Comment: Consider what this does with `s='1.'`.

Comment: @user2357112 fixed - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `split`, but I can't imagine why you'd want to.

```
def format_str(number):
    elements = number.split('.')
    elements.append('0')
    return '{}.{}'.format(elements[0], elements[1][0])
```

Comment: Consider what this does with `number='1.'`.